# Using raycaster method refreshObjects() in AFrame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am wondering how to use a method of a component in an entity
for example.: I have the entity with a cursor and a raycaster component:

```
<a-entity id=”raycaster_cursor" raycaster="objects: .clickable" cursor=”fuse .....
```

now i want to use the refreshObjects() Method of the raycaster component. How do i do that?
Am I simply not understanding the concept of entities and components?

I tried to do it like this:

```
var myCursor = document.querySelector(”#raycaster_cursor");
myCursor.aycaster.refreshObjects();
```

and like this:

```
var myCursor = document.querySelector(”#raycaster_cursor");
myCursor.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
```

But thats not working.

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/core/component.html#accessing-a-component’s-methods-and-properties

```
// <a-entity foo>
var fooComponent = document.querySelector('[foo]').components.foo;
console.log(fooComponent.barProperty);
fooComponent.bazMethod();
```